# Is there any time constructible function $f$ such that $f(n) = o(n\lg n)$ ？

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

In Sipser's *Introduction to the Theory of Computation*, the definition of *time-constructible* function is,

> a funciton $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$, where $f(n)$ is at least $O(n\lg n)$, is called *time constructible* if the function that maps the string $1^n$ to the binary representation of $f(n)$ is computable in time $O(f(n))$

In this definition, $f(n)\geq O(n\lg n)$. I found someone discussed why $f(n)\geq O(n\lg n)$ is sensible from the viewpoint of the *time hierarchy theorem* [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/143067/why-there-is-log-n-factor-in-time-constructible-definition). But I want to know, if I remove this restriction, **is there any $f(n) = o(n\lg n)$ time constructible**?

---

For $f(n) = n$, I have a proof that $f$ is not time constructible below.

First, as the exercise 7.49 in Sipser's *Introduction to the Theory of Computation*, if $f(n)=o(n\lg n)$, then any $L\in \mathrm{TIME}(f(n))$ is a regular language. A proof sketch is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84040/does-dtimeon-regular).

And then, if $f(n) = n$ is time constructible, I can get the binary representation of $1^n$ in $O(n)$, then I can decide whether $n$ is the power of $2$ by simply checking the binary representation.

But, $L=\{1^{n}\mid n=2^k, k=0,1,...\}$ is not a regular language, so there is a contradiction. This means that $f(n)=n$ is not time constructible.

---

So I have two questions.

- Is my proof above correct? In fact I did not find any proof of $f(n)=n$ time constructible or not, so I am not sure.
- Is it possible to prove any $f(n)=o(n\lg n)$ is not time constructible?

Thank you for your help.